# What does "0o", "0x", and "0b" mean in Python?

Tags: python

I don't understand what these prefixes mean:

```
a = 0o1010
b = 0x1010
c = 0b1010
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

It outputs the following values, but what does the `0o`, `0x` and `0b` parts mean ?

```
520 
4112
10
```

Comment: These are used to distinguish octal, hexadecimal, and binary literals.

Comment: These are representations of numbers in different number systems: `0o` is the Octal (base 8) system, `0x` is the hexadecimal (base 16) system, and `0b` is the binary (base 2) system.

Thus, a is equal to 520 (1*8 + 1*512) i.e., 8^1 + 8^3, b is equal to 16^1 + 16^3 and c is equal to 2^3 + 2^1

Answer (score 3):

In Python, `0o`, `0x` and `0b` are prefix notations used to represent numbers in different number systems.

`0o` is used to indicate an octal (base-8) number. Octal numbers use the digits 0 to 7.

`0x` is used to indicate a hexadecimal (base-16) number. Hexadecimal numbers use the digits 0 to 9 and the letters A to F to represent values 10 to 15.

`0b` is used to indicate a binary (base-2) number. Binary numbers use only the digits 0 and 1.

For example, the number 75 can be represented in decimal, octal, hexadecimal, and binary notation as follows:

- Decimal: `75`
- Octal: `0o113`
- Hexadecimal: `0x4B`
- Binary: `0b1001011`

Answer (score 0):

The prefix represents how numbers can be written in different number systems.

```
0o --> Octal i.e. base 8 ( number ranges from 0 to 7 then it adds a place )
0x --> Hexadecimal i.e. base 16 ( number ranges from 0 to 15 then it adds a place )
0b --> Binary base 2 ( number ranges from 0 to 1 then it adds a place )
```

To out this "base" in a context, our regular number system is decimal, base 10. i.e a Number ranges from 0 to 9 and then we add a place - 10.

Thus

10 in Octal is decimal 8

10 in Hex   is decimal 16

10 in Binary is decimal 2

You get the idea. Go to a website like [this](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/octal-to-decimal.html) to do your conversion of 1010 and see the results.